# trying to make OpenCV 3.2.0 work with virtualenv

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 2.7 and virtualenv & virtualenvwrapper.

By following [this guide](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/) I managed to get the following script working with my system Python2.7 which has `cv2` globally installed.

I used this script to install it:

```
######################################
# INSTALL OPENCV ON UBUNTU OR DEBIAN #
######################################

# |         THIS SCRIPT IS TESTED CORRECTLY ON         |
# |----------------------------------------------------|
# | OS             | OpenCV       | Test | Last test   |
# |----------------|--------------|------|-------------|
# | Ubuntu 16.04.2 | OpenCV 3.2.0 | OK   | 20 May 2017 |
# | Debian 8.8     | OpenCV 3.2.0 | OK   | 20 May 2017 |
# | Debian 9.0     | OpenCV 3.2.0 | OK   | 25 Jun 2017 |

# 1. KEEP UBUNTU OR DEBIAN UP TO DATE

sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y autoremove


# 2. INSTALL THE DEPENDENCIES

# Build tools:
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential cmake

# GUI (if you want to use GTK instead of Qt, replace 'qt5-default' with 'libgtkglext1-dev' and remove '-DWITH_QT=ON' option in CMake):
sudo apt-get install -y qt5-default libvtk6-dev

# Media I/O:
sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev libwebp-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libopenexr-dev libgdal-dev

# Video I/O:
sudo apt-get install -y libdc1394-22-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev yasm libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libv4l-dev libxine2-dev

# Parallelism and linear algebra libraries:
sudo apt-get install -y libtbb-dev libeigen3-dev

# Python:
sudo apt-get install -y python-dev python-tk python-numpy python3-dev python3-tk python3-numpy

# Documentation:
sudo apt-get install -y doxygen

# UI stuff
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev libatlas-base-dev gfortran


# 3. INSTALL THE LIBRARY (YOU CAN CHANGE '3.2.0' FOR THE LAST STABLE VERSION)
sudo apt-get install -y unzip wget

# opencv contrib
wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/3.2.0.zip -O opencv_contrib-3.2.0.zip
unzip opencv_contrib-3.2.0.zip
rm opencv_contrib-3.2.0.zip

# opencv
wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.2.0.zip
unzip 3.2.0.zip
rm 3.2.0.zip
mv opencv-3.2.0 OpenCV-3.2.0
cd OpenCV-3.2.0

mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D WITH_QT=ON \
    -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
    -D FORCE_VTK=ON \
    -D WITH_TBB=ON \
    -D WITH_GDAL=ON \
    -D WITH_XINE=ON \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
    ..

make -j4
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig


# 4. EXECUTE SOME OPENCV EXAMPLES AND COMPILE A DEMONSTRATION

# To complete this step, please visit 'http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian'.
```

The following script below works great with that system-wide installation:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('some_img.jpg')
```

Though this one doesn't - even the system Python can't read videos for some reason...

```
import cv2

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = video_capture.read()
print ret  # always False
```

but I want it to work with my virtualenv. So I recompiled OpenCV with:

```
cmake -D WITH_QT=ON \
    -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
    -D FORCE_VTK=ON \
    -D WITH_TBB=ON \
    -D WITH_GDAL=ON \
    -D WITH_XINE=ON \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/me/code/myproject/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules \
    -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.envs/myenv/bin/python \
    ..

make -j4
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Here's the CMake log:

```
-- Found VTK ver. 6.2.0 (usefile: /usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.2/UseVTK.cmake)
-- Caffe:   NO
-- Protobuf:   YES
-- Glog:   NO
-- freetype2:   YES
-- harfbuzz:    YES
-- Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Glog/Gflags
-- freetype2:   YES
-- harfbuzz:    YES
-- Checking for modules 'tesseract;lept'
--   No package 'tesseract' found
--   No package 'lept' found
-- Tesseract:   NO
-- Check contents of vgg_generated_48.i ...
-- Check contents of vgg_generated_64.i ...
-- Check contents of vgg_generated_80.i ...
-- Check contents of vgg_generated_120.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_bgm.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_bgm_bi.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_bgm_hd.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_binboost_064.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_binboost_128.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_binboost_256.i ...
-- Check contents of boostdesc_lbgm.i ...
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.2.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               817bd7b-dirty
-- 
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /home/me/code/myproject/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules
--     Version control (extra):     817bd7b-dirty
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2017-07-20T18:25:26Z
--     Host:                        Linux 4.8.0-58-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.5.1
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.4.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent Qt5::OpenGL /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so /usr/lib/libgdal.so dc1394 xine avcodec-ffmpeg avformat-ffmpeg avutil-ffmpeg swscale-ffmpeg Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so vtkRenderingOpenGL vtkImagingHybrid vtkIOImage vtkCommonDataModel vtkCommonMath vtkCommonCore vtksys vtkCommonMisc vtkCommonSystem vtkCommonTransforms vtkCommonExecutionModel vtkDICOMParser vtkIOCore /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so vtkmetaio /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so vtkImagingCore vtkRenderingCore vtkCommonColor vtkFiltersExtraction vtkFiltersCore vtkFiltersGeneral vtkCommonComputationalGeometry vtkFiltersStatistics vtkImagingFourier vtkalglib vtkFiltersGeometry vtkFiltersSources vtkInteractionStyle vtkRenderingLOD vtkFiltersModeling vtkIOPLY vtkIOGeometry /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so vtkFiltersTexture vtkRenderingFreeType /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so vtkftgl vtkIOExport vtkRenderingAnnotation vtkImagingColor vtkRenderingContext2D vtkRenderingGL2PS vtkRenderingContextOpenGL /usr/lib/libgl2ps.so vtkRenderingLabel dl m pthread rt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so tbb
--     3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann hdf imgproc ml photo reg surface_matching video viz dnn freetype fuzzy imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect plot superres ts xobjdetect xphoto bgsegm bioinspired dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib cvv datasets rgbd stereo tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow phase_unwrapping stitching structured_light java python2 python3
--     Disabled:                    world contrib_world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cnn_3dobj matlab sfm
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT 5.x:                      YES (ver 5.5.1)
--     QT OpenGL support:           YES (Qt5::OpenGL 5.5.1)
--     OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so)
--     VTK support:                 YES (ver 6.2.0)
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x0202)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.54)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.6)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2.2.0)
--     GDAL:                        /usr/lib/libgdal.so
--     GDCM:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.4)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 56.60.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 56.40.101)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 54.31.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     Aravis SDK:                  NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        YES (ver 1.2.6)
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 4.4 interface 9002)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
--          at:                     /home/me/code/myproject/OpenCV-3.2.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Lapack:                  NO
--     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.92)
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--     Use OpenVX:                  NO
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
--     Include path:                /home/me/code/myproject/OpenCV-3.2.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/me/.envs/myenv/bin/python (ver 2.7.12)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
--     numpy:                       /home/me/.envs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.1)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.5.2)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.0)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.5/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /home/me/.envs/myenv/bin/python
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.9.6)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java wrappers:               YES
--     Java tests:                  YES
-- 
--   Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     /usr/bin/doxygen (ver 1.8.11)
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/me/code/myproject/OpenCV-3.2.0/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
```

Unfortunately, while this works and I can import `cv2` in the shell, it cannot read video using the above script, probably due to incorrect compilation or linking of `ffmpeg`? The confusing part is the system-wide installation of OpenCV works fine, even without ffmpeg installed!

What am I doing wrong? How can I get OpenCV working with a virtualenv?

====

EDIT: Running the C++ video writing example has this result:

```
$ cd /home/me/code/myproject/OpenCV-3.2.0/build/bin
$ ./cpp-tutorial-video-write ../../samples/data/vtest.avi R Y
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This program shows how to write video files.
You can extract the R or G or B color channel of the input video.
Usage:
./video-write <input_video_name> [ R | G | B] [Y | N]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0xffffffff/'����' is not found (format 'avi / AVI (Audio Video Interleaved)')'

(cpp-tutorial-video-write:19523): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Gstreamer Opencv backend does not support this codec.) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file /home/me/code/myproject/OpenCV-3.2.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 1388
VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_GStreamer(filename, fourcc, fps, frameSize, is_color)): raised OpenCV exception:

/home/me/code/myproject/OpenCV-3.2.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1388: error: (-210) Gstreamer Opencv backend does not support this codec. in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open

Could not open the output video for write: ../../samples/data/vtest.avi
```

And the `opencv_test_videoio` unit test reports the following: https://pastebin.com/q4mf224Q

However, running the c++ video starter example DOES work, with the following command and output, I can see the webcam working and streaming video in the highgui interface:

```
$ ./cpp-example-videocapture_starter 0
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: device 0: Unable to query number of channels
(ERROR)icvOpenAVI_XINE(): Unable to initialize video driver.
GStreamer: Error opening bin: no element "0"
press space to save a picture. q or esc to quit
init done
opengl support available
```

Comment: You may need some of the packages I list here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44972255/2836621

Comment: Just to be totally sure you're using the right build, it might be worth printing `cv2.__file__` as part of your script.

Comment: I made a [step by step guide](https://asettouf.github.io/opencv/install/python2/virtualenv/ubuntu/2017/07/23/How-to-install-opencv3-with-Python2-inside-a-virtualenv.html) to make the installation (just tried it today and it worked), can you check it? It's mostly the same as above besides the end where you need the `cv2.so` from the system wide *site-packages* linked inside your virtualenv (see the end)

Comment: @ArthurTacca: printing `cv2.__file__` shows the following: `/home/me/.envs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/cv2.so` which is what I'd guess it should show.

Comment: What @ArthurTacca means, is that you're sure you are using the same cv2.so than the one used in your system and that supports video usage? (it might be worth to compare the md5/shaX hashes between `/home/me/.envs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/c‌​v2.so` and `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so`)

Answer (score 2):

According to the guide, you installed `libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev` which are necessary for using a camera and decode the audio/video stream.

I think the CMake output/log should have given you some hints, I suggest you provide us a link of a pastebin/gist of this log.

For example, what do you have below this line in the CMake log? (you should have a lot of yes)

`--   Video I/O:`

And at this one:

`--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built: <list of opencv modules>`

Does `<list of opencv modules>` contains "videoio" ?

Another stupid test: does you camera works? Do you have a /dev/video0 file? Can you see the video stream with vlc or cheese?

---

Edit

I see you do not have gstreamer, 
Could you try to install the following libraries: `libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev` and recompile?

V4L2 should be enough, and you have it, but [according to the sources](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b500ae2d21e858bebd68b34b6cfef352979c269a/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp#L196) gstreamer can also be used for video capture.
So there is a low probability but not negligible this solve your problem.

Other questions:

- what happens when you use a video file instead of your webcam?
- I see the (unit) tests were compiled, did they all passed?
- I see the cpp samples were compiled, could you try `cpp-example-videocapture_basic` or `cpp-example-videocapture_starter`, do they give you an error?

Comment: Yes, `/dev/video0` exists, and `cheese` works just fine. I included as an edit in the original post the OpenCV CMake log, hopefully that is clearer - should have done that in the first place!

Comment: This is clearer, thank you. So I edited my answer with additional questions.

Comment: tried `gstreamer`, that didn't seem to help. Using a video file didn't work either. Here's the output of test `opencv_test_videoio` (https://pastebin.com/w4xSC3ti) - you're right, definitely some funny stuff going on with gstreamer and video driver. could it be that I need to delete my build folder each time or that my build process isn't updating somehow? (since I have gstreamer now)

Comment: Some of the errors displayed from the tests come from missing input data, but not all of them. 
I think gstreamer was seen by cmake.
Could you try with the "libv4l-dev" package and run cmake with also -DWITH_LIBV4L=ON
I saw some people had troubles with libv4l2, but libv4l worked.
If you cannot open a video also, ffmpeg/libav could be the culprit.
You have no error message/exception/assertion when you use the sample or your code?

Comment: Already had `libv4l-dev` installed, but added that CMake flag. No change - still can't load video from webcam or disk.

Comment: In fact your CMake log displayed `V4L/V4L2:  NO/YES` which means you have V4L2 but not V4L.

Comment: Does video_capture.grab() returns True or False?
Also, could you provide your CMakeCache.txt?
Could you compile with -DCV_INSTRUMENT_REGION=ON
This would enable to know what part of the code in the OpenCV library is run.
It is very unfortunate you have no error message associated with your problem.
The only solution I see then to find the origin of the problem would be to perform debugging of the cvCreateCameraCapture() and read() functions in the OpenCV library, eg with gdb.

Comment: `grab()` returns False. I am seeing the following error when running the c++ examples for webcam: `/home/me/code/myproject/OpenCV-3.2.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1388: error: (-210) Gstreamer Opencv backend does not support this codec. in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open`. I've also added the full trace to the question. It's weird because I have `gstreamer` installed and everything looks good from the CMake log.

Comment: Sample being run was `$ ./cpp-tutorial-video-write ../../samples/data/vtest.avi R Y`

Comment: However, the video capture cpp example does work?? `$ ./cpp-example-videocapture_starter 0
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: device 0: Unable to query number of channels
(ERROR)icvOpenAVI_XINE(): Unable to initialize video driver.
GStreamer: Error opening bin: no element "0"
press space to save a picture. q or esc to quit
init done
opengl support available` - I can see the webcam / it works properly, but not in Python hmm.

Comment: To read a .avi file (for the cpp-tutorial-video-write test) you need libxine2 (and probably libxine2-dev too). Btw from the unit tests I see you do not have this lib installed. Fun OpenCV is using V4L and not V4L2 to open your webcam. I guess the sample cpp_example-videocapture_basic should work too. Does video_capture.isOpened() returns True? Strange cpp-example-videocapture_starter displayed an error message but worked, one interpretation would be that the 1st read() calls failed, but the successive ones succeeded, probably you would get the same behaviour in Python.

Comment: `libxine2` and `libxine2-dev` are already installed. Also in my latest updated log from CMake I have both V4L and V4L2 installed. `isOpened` returns `False`. I'm scratching my head pretty good over here. What else can I check?

Comment: I don't understand - no matter how many times I triple check if I have V4L installed or Xine installed, the CMake never finds them and it keeps saying `NO/YES` when `sudo apt-get install v4l-utils` succeeds.

Comment: I cannot explain why it works in the C++ version and not in the Python one. You are sure you do not have an older version of OpenCV installed somewhere? Is `cv2.__version__` correct? If `pkg-config --modversion libv4l1; pkg-config --modversion libv4l2; pkg-config --modversion libxine` give you version number, then the OpenCV CMake scripts must find v4l1,  v4l2 and libxine. About Cmake, you can try a `rm -r CMakeFiles; rm CMakeCache.txt` before running cmake again.