# Cannot open video files in openCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3

Please help to fix the video opening issue using opencv on raspberry pi 3. Almost 3 weeks I am fighting with this issue.
This is my code:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("/home/pi/Documents/forRaspberry/small.mp4")
print (cap.isOpened())
```

And when running, the cap isOpened returns false: 
(same False result with cap.grab() )

```
Python 3.4.2 (/usr/bin/python3)
>>> %Run roundBound_modif_withVideo.py
False
```

I am using 3.2.0 opencv version and 3.4.2 python version.

I assumed the issue is connected with FFMPEG. And put all my efforts to fix it. These are what I have tried so far:
1)  I build opencCV with FFMPEG on 
 `WITH_FFMPEG                      ON`    
Does not fix the issue
2) FFPMEG is not installed in my raspbain. I read in forums that `libav-tools` replaces the FFMPEG. So installed libav-tools. Still not helped
3) When I do cmake it prints following:

```
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       avcodec:                   NO
--       avformat:                  NO
--       avutil:                    NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       avresample:                YES (ver 2.1.0)
```

Read in forum that I need to alias  ffmpeg to `avconv` (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=125367). Still does not help

I think should I install ffmpeg in raspbain separately?

Can this issue be connected with version mismatches of some packages? Can someone please explain how I can know all matching pacakges versions list for my opencv and pyhton versions?

Comment: Try some of the packages I had success with https://stackoverflow.com/a/44972255/2836621

Comment: thanks, but there is no such package as ffmpeg((
also when in linux terminal you type ffmpeg, does it work?